# Nodejs looping with callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am new to nodejs callback function. I have to find phones list between two price ranges given, if there are no 15 phones in the obtained list , I have to change the price range until I got 15 phones. Actually I wrote function for searching phones from database in another file, from that file I send callback to calling function. After I got callback I have to check the array size if array size is less than 15 then change the price range and have to call the same function like Recursion or looping. I am unable to handle the callback function. Please help me to write the correct code.

```
 while(true ){
            console.log("around came")
             Search.findBestMobile(context.end_price , context.start_price , function(data){
                 console.log("Best Mobile");
                 size = data.hits.hits.length;
                 if(size >= 15){
                     context.phone_list = makeStringFromArray(data.hits.hits);
                     cb(context);
                     break;
                 }else{
                     context.start_price += 1000;
                     context.end_price   += 1000;
                 }
             });
         }
```

But in above code, break  is unreachable statement. I can't handle it. please help me.

Comment: `while(true)` - This is not a good idea.

Comment: yes I know, how to modify that

Comment: You are already using callback (just add one more in else branch), so not sure what is the problem.

Comment: okk, i am trying to remove infinite loop

Comment: If we knew what `Search` is and how that callback is being called, it'd be easier to help you.

Comment: **First**: recursive DB-calls are rarely a good solution, would suggest a two-step-solution, where you first "partition" the DB by price-ranges and therefore know which range you have to select to get sufficient results. **Second:** What currency are we talking about? 1000 bucks are a step to me that would contain (almost) all phones available. About how many results/phones do you have per this 1000 buck price-range? Just to get an idea, of how many recursive calls we're talking about.

Comment: To your current solution: increasing start_price along with end_price makes only sense if you concat the results. And from a customers point of view, you micht want to extend the price-range in both directions (equally): to decrese the start_price and increase the end_price. Then, why do you already serialize the Array? What data does context also contain? And who holds a reference to that object? This seems like one of these places where I agree with FP, that mutation could bite you in the ass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use asynchronous code in synchronous way. That simply won't do, because callback can be called seconds later. Beside that break won't work if called inside function. 
What are you really doing is calling Search.findBestMobile infinite number of times. Node.js has only single thread that it uses to run your code and you are blocking it. So callbacks won't be called.

What you need to do is to use recursion or other async approach to loops.
One simple way of doing it would be to call your outer function again with new context.

```
function searchRange(context, cb) {
    Search.findBestMobile(context.end_price , context.start_price , function(data){
                 console.log("Best Mobile");
                 size = data.hits.hits.length;
                 if(size >= 15){
                     context.phone_list = makeStringFromArray(data.hits.hits);
                     cb(context);
                 }else{
                     context.start_price += 1000;
                     context.end_price   += 1000;
                     searchRange(context, cb);
                 }
             });
}
```

Comment: Remember that node.js **is not** single-threaded, what actually happens is that a single thread runs your code and delegates the I/O-bound work to a thread pool as stated here: http://www.haneycodes.net/to-node-js-or-not-to-node-js/

Comment: Yeah, but your code runs only in single thread. As far as I know at least. So yes I made mistake by writing that node.js is single threaded. But blocking issue of while(true) still holds true.

Comment: Yes, your answer is entirely correct and I believe you were able to pinpoint the error, I was just trying to fix an wrong concept that some node.js developers have that node.js is single-threaded (entirely)

Comment: Ok, I get it. And you were right to do so. I know how node.js (and browsers) are not single threaded, but they use only single thread to run js. Well... not counting web workers and other similar solutions.